# How to "play" with MEDIA queries in css?

Tags: css

I have two monitors. According to `jQuery(window).width()` first is `1906` and second `1352`. So if window width is 1352 or less I need to change `.container` properties. I tried something like

```
@media (width: 1350px) {
@media (max-width: 1352px) {
@media (width <= 1352px) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1352px) {
    .container {
    }
}
```

What this translates to is apply the CSS for screen widths `<=1352`

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1352px){
  .container {
    /* change something */
  }
}
```

should work. Also, if you use Chrome, it [lets you "inspect" media queries](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#media-queries) in a fairly easy to understand way.